# react-native run-android builds an old version of the code onto device

Tags: react-native

This occurs in both production and dev builds. I can connect to the dev server, reload, and the new code is built and runs on the device.

Step-by-step of what I have tried:

1. Modify code.
2. Re-bundle:

`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`

3. `./gradlew clean`
4. `react-native run-android` - Builds old version
5. `react-native run-android --variant=release` - Builds old version

Is there any way to completely wipe the `android` build and build from scratch? My gut tells me that `run-android` is not performing a full clean build.

Comment: Did you try resetting the bundler cache?

Comment: If you're referring to `react-native start --reset-cache`, I tried that and it did not work. If you're referring to something else, please share. I did however find a solution, but it's probably overkill: I deleted my android folder, ran `react-native upgrade`, re-bundled and ran `react-native run-android`. I am sure there is a better fix than this.

Comment: you can delete `android/app/src/main/assets` folder before re-bundle

Comment: @Akis The problem has somehow come back again and clearing the assets folder, rebundling deletes all my fonts + images from the newly built apk. Is there another step that I am missing? Thanks.

Comment: @Biiiiiird - were you manage to find the issue? I am stuck on exact same problem.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

1. Delete files inside directory android/app/src/main/assets.
2. run `$ react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`
3. `$ react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's not exactly what you have faced. But I was creating a `staging` buildType in my **react native project** too, the build was fine (after dealing with some problems), but for some reason **it was loading an old version of the app too**.

After changing the buildType from `staging` to `releaseStaging`, it started to build as expected.

I hope this answer helps anyone that might land in this page just like I did.

I've answered in another topic too with [more specific instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72759992/19110863).